# JSP Tag file that outputs the result (return value) to a variable instread of printing it out

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

I have a Custom JSP Tag File (Java Class) that extends TagSupport class. In this class, I have the doEndTag method that computes something and the output is written as shown below:

```
public class ScopeTag extends TagSupport {
    private Scope scope;
    public int doEndTag() throws JspTagException {
        String content = null;
        content = String.valueOf(srs.getParameterDatasByScope(scope).size()); // src is my service class
        pageContext.getOut().print((content == null) ? "" : content);
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Now I use this Tag Class in my JSP as:

```
<td><i:scope type="numOfParamData" scope="${scope}"/> parameter rules</td>
```

Now instead of printing the value inside a td element, I want to store it into a variable for further processing. Say for example, I want to see it the return value is 0 or not.

I would like to write the Tag Java class such that I can use the tag something similar to the JSTL tag `fmt:parseDate` as shown below.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${now}" var="parsedEmpDate" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />  
<p>Parsed Date: <c:out value="${parsedEmpDate}" /></p>
```

Here the result (formatted data) is stored into the variable `parsedEmpDate`

So in order to achieve something like the fmt:parseDate, what changes I have to do in the Tag class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question (my need) is almost same as that in this thread: [JSP tag file that either outputs its body or returns it in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042518/jsp-tag-file-that-either-outputs-its-body-or-returns-it-in-a-variable)

However, the answers in this thread were related to writing the tag library code in a `.tag` file, which is new to me. All I know on writing a tag library is to code it as a java class. And that is why I created this thread.

Nevertheless, I went ahead to take some hints/help from the above thread and made up my own solution:
I used this line of text as my solution - `I know that the caller can achieve this by wrapping the custom tag in a c:set, but this is less elegant than simply declaring a "var"`

Here is the code:

```
<c:set var="optin">
   <i:scope type="paramData" scope="${scope}" paramNum="40100"/>
</c:set>
```

No changes done to the tag library java class..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can use SimpleDateFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html;

Example:

```
Date today = new Date();

        //If you print Date, you will get un formatted output
        System.out.println("Today is : " + today);

        //formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : " + date);

        //Another Example of formatting Date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
        DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd/MM/yy pattern : " + date);

        //formatting Date with time information
        DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS");
        date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : " + date);

        //SimpleDateFormat example - Date with timezone information
        DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS Z");
        date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SSZ : " + date);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Today is : Fri Nov 02 16:11:27 IST 2012
Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : 02-11-2012
Today in dd/MM/yy pattern : 02/11/12
Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : 02-11-12:16:11:316
Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SSZ : 02-11-12:16:11:316 +0530
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the issue I am facing here is not with how to format the date. I need to code the Custom JSP Tag class so that the computed value/result is stored into a variable which can then be used in the JSP

Comment: So your problem is you don't know how to store the scope value into a variable within JSP page?

Comment: I would like to use my tag something like below: <i:scope scope="${scope}" var="result"/> - With this the return value from the tag class will be placed into the var - "result"

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you wants, but can you try: <c:set var="myVar" value="{$scope}" scope="request" /> Now you can see this variable value like:  <c:out value="${requestScope.myVar}" /> This is the case if you are requesting your value within request.